# How does finishing my bachelor's degree in 4 years affect my academic career?

Tags: masters, united-states, application, bachelor

I started university early and some unexpected events happened and my first year wasn't so great, however, I have high scores like +100/110 and a very good CV with work experience and research papers.
I don't think I'll finish my degree in 3 years, maybe 4 at the most.
At the end of the 4th year, I will be 21 years old.
I wanted to know do I have a chance with good universities in general like the top 10 or IVY LEAGUE in the USA.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you plan to fund your master's degree at an Ivy in the US (I assume from your choice of tags you're looking for masters not PhD)? 4 years is a normal bachelor's in the US. If it took you longer because you failed a lot of classes, the thing holding you back will be the failed classes not the time.

Comment: And, frankly, given the state of the world for much of the last 4 years (i.e. Covid), many students are going to have transcripts that are going to look different than in previous times (and, hopefully, future times).

Comment: I started a bachelors degree in the fall of 1999.  I completed a bachelors degree in the winter of 2009.  I now have a phd from a University of California (not the best UC, but it is a UC, nevertheless).  No one actually cares how long it takes you to complete a degree, as long as you do so, and can get good letters from people you worked with (or have other experience which is relevant and interesting to a selection committee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people in the US take four years for a bachelors. That isn't a problem. Taking four years may actually be an advantage if it lets you take a few more advanced courses in your field. And, it is even better if you can get a bit of research experience with a professor. And most folks are about 21 when they finish. No problem there either.

Also, most students in most fields don't earn a masters before starting doctoral study. A doctoral student with a TA is a resource to all R1 institutions since they help support the undergraduate program. That isn't open to most masters students, who are almost always self funded. If you are that good, think about doctoral programs.

But there are no guarantees about admission to top 10 or even top 30 US graduate institutions. For some of those the number admitted is small and the competition is intense. While I don't discourage applying to such places it isn't optimal to apply to *only* those places. Cast a wide net. Cover the top 50, at least. You may get lucky, but there is an element of luck in getting admitted to such places.

There are excellent advisors and excellent opportunities at almost all R1 institutions in most fields. Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good.